# How to use variables in Twig filter 'replace'

Tags: variables, drupal, replace, twig

Handing over an array from php of form

```
$repl_arr = array('serach-string1' => 'replace1', ...)
```

to a Twig template I would like to replace strings in a Twig variable per replace filter similar to this:

```
{{ block | replace({ repl_arr }) }}
```

That does not function and neither a variable loop like

```
{% for key,item in repla_arr %}
  {% set var = block | replace({ key : item }) %}
{% endfor %}
```

does. What is wrong with it? How could it work?

Comment: Can you give me an example (just a good example) of what your `block` variable looks like and then I should have a solution.

Comment: The answer of DarkBee excellently described the usage of replace filter with a hash (array).

@alvin-bunk
The second point indeed is the variable 'block'. It is a render array (I didn't have that in mind). So replace  doesn't work with it. And when I do

{% set output %}
  {{ block }}
{% endset %}
{{ output | replace(replaces) }}
then html characters are escaped like e.g. &lt;

Comment: Seems I found it, output with 
{% autoescape false %} ... {% endautoescape %}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either you pass the whole array, or you loop the replaces.

But when looping the replaces you need to wrap `key` and `value` in parentheses to force interpolation of those

```
{% set replaces = {
    '{site}'     : '{stackoverflow}',
    '{date}'  : "NOW"|date('d-m-Y'),
} %}

{% set haystack = '{site} foobar {site} {date} bar' %}


{{ haystack | replace(replaces) }}

{% set output = haystack %}
{% for key, value in replaces %}
    {% set output = output|replace({(key) : (value),}) %}
{% endfor %} 
{{ output }}
```

[fiddle](https://twigfiddle.com/ycdjf9)

Comment: Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?