# How to replace a value of a variable with another variable in twig?

Tags: twig

I have a string in twig that needs to be replaced with some words.

`{% set myvar = 'Hello World' %}`

`{% set firstvar = 'Hello' %}`

`{% set secondvar = 'Test' %}`

If I want to replace Hello with the test below code doesn't work.

`{{ myvar|replace({"{{firstvar}}":"{{secondvar}}"}) }}`

My expected output is : Test World

What is the wrong with the code. I ve searched everywhere but I couldn't find it.

Comment: From the documentation it looks like you just need to get rid of the double quotes (they're already strings)

Comment: @SterlingArcher No luck. I get below error after removing the double quotes `Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax: "A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{"."`

Comment: Ah! I think I found an answer for you. Try the marked answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943880/str-replace-in-twig). Looks like you have to use parentheses when replacing string vars

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use variables in Twig filter 'replace'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794257/how-to-use-variables-in-twig-filter-replace)